# Encryption of CAB Files using Installshield

Tags: installshield, cab

I was wondering if it is possible to prevent access to .cab files using InstallShield Software. Maybe there is any option in the software.. It should encrypt .cab file, maybe with a certificate file?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to encrypt using InstallShield but at the file level. This is applicable if you're using Installscript project. Refer this -

https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/FeatureSettings.htm

For the basic MSI project, you could sign the .cab file but I didn't find any option to encrypt here. You could probably use some external script to perform this job and can try to decrypt it using a custom action at the initial phase of installation.